# Simplify expression cross/dot products

Tags: cross-product

Can the following expression be simplified? In particular, I would like to remove the denominator:

$\frac{( b \times (a \times b)) \cdot (b \times (a\times b))}{(a\times b) \cdot (a\times b)}$

where $a$ and $b$ are 3 dimensional vectors.

Comment: A vector dotted with itself is its magnitude squared, and the magnitude of $a \times b$ is $|a| |b| \sin \theta$.

Comment: Dot products are usually written without a transpose.

Comment: Transpose removed.

Comment: Ah, so the numerator is $\left( |b| |a \times b| \sin \pi/2 \right)^2$. So yes, the $|a \times b|^2$ cancels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression is $\|b\|^2$, because $b$ and $c:=a\times b$ are orthogonal and $\|b\times c\|=\|b\|\|c\|.$